# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn throwing IndexOutOfRange on cell click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am programatically adding a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a DataGridView at one point it was working - but for some reason it is now always throwing an Index Out of Range Exception any time I click the cell, or the dropdown. The Debugger is trying to call up external code asking my to uncheck the just my code (so I did) and I still can't see what is happening. I add the column and then I set the DataGridView.DataSource - the column data is of type String ; I populate the combobox with GetGradesList.ToArray() - the items are there, the binding seems to work and reflect the items correctly.

Here is the snippet that adds the Column;

```
Sub  AddComboBoxColumn(dc As DataColumn )        
        Dim dgvCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                dgvCol.DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName
                dgvCol.Name = dc.ColumnName
                dgvCol.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

                dgvCol.Items.AddRange(GetGradesList.ToArray())
                dgvCol.ReadOnly = False
                dgvCol.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCol)

End Sub
```

As I was typing this I tried removing the DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation and this worked around the problem ; so my question is why is this happening with DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation - I am subscribed to the CellValidating Event  and return if there is a RowIndex = -1

Any one with any ideas why I am getting the Index Out of Range Exception ?

**EDIT 6-30-2016**
Data Source is shown below - bindingSource bound to dataTable which has rows from the Database Query.

```
Private Sub LoadRecipes(ByVal recipeID As Integer)

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    query = "SELECT * FROM tblBays Where RecipeID = " + "'" + recipeID.ToString() + "'"

    dt = RetrieveData(query) 

    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    If DataGridView1.Columns.Count < 1 Then
        CreateDataGridColumns(dt)
    End If

    bsBins.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
    bsBins.SuspendBinding()
    bsBins.DataSource = Nothing
    bsBins.DataSource = dt
    bsBins.ResumeBinding()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bsBins


    bsBins.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
    '   DataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation

End Sub
```

[image: Picture Screen Shot]

Comment: Assuming you have a bound datasource, can you show us the datasource?  I ran into a similar problem the other day when using a List<> for my datasource, and changing it to a bindingList fixed this problem.  Not sure if that is actually the problem, but seeing how you get your data would probably be helpful regardless.

Comment: @jpaugh78 Added code as per your request

Comment: What is the datatype for Grade in the main table? surely not text, in which case it cant find, say `5` in the list, the result is -1 which is out of range.

Comment: @Plutonix  - Grade varchar(80) in DataBase, - it does not need to find 5  or 1 or 3 as those are the values that are written and read - what exists in the ComboBox forces the selection to one of those possible values which are dictated by a different system - not a db.

Comment: I tried to mimic whats there complete with bindingsource and cannot duplicate the problem.  But a) if all you are binding to a dgv, you dont need a bindingsource.  It offers some nice methods but isnt really needed for  binding,  b) you tagged this as c#, but that is VB code.  You could add code to the DataError event to maybe find out what the problem is.

Comment: @Plutonix ah yes I did tag it as c# , I always use c# except this one project I am forced into vb.net. , I am using v4.51

Comment: @Ken Setting things `= Nothing` and then setting them to something is not useful. Also, you haven't shown us the code that should run when the Grade comboboxes are clicked.

Comment: @Andrew Morton - setting to nothing means I do not need to clear each item - very quick when changing the data. Also there is no code for the Combobox click event - I do not need it. There is a list of items, the combobox changes values the cell is in edit mode, the cell is bound to the datasource and therefore the source should be updated.